# Letter of Egorov to Lusin

Tags: teaching

I heard that there is a famous letter between Egorov and Lusin , which best reflects relation between the teacher student duo. Can anyone provide any link of that letter?

Comment: Can you read Russian (if not then you should say so)? The Russian Wikipedia page for Egorov includes an excerpt from a letter from Egorov to Lusin with some bibliographic information after the excerpt. Just search that page for the word письма.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it. I don't know Russian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the letter of 4th August 1905, you can read it [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=BFsnWXkqZaMC&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=Egorov%20Lusin%20Letter&source=bl&ots=A2gkpyiLIH&sig=Ay-wmYEzvf-adJUBGyhI_uM2JaM&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW9M--vZLUAhXHcRQKHWoJB0kQ6AEIODAC#v=onepage&q=Egorov%20Lusin%20Letter&f=false) in English translation (from Russian Mathematicians in the 20th Century by Yakov Sinai). There are also excerpts of other letters by Egorov.